# Find out the associated file that opened your activity

Tags: java, android

I associated a file type with my android app. When i open such a file, it opens my activity and everything is fine so far. But how do i know what specific file opened my activity? I can't find any information :/
I would be thankful for every answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> But how do i know what specific file opened my activity?

Call `getIntent().getData()` to get the `Uri` that was used as part of starting up your activity.